# Instructions to setup Launch4j for jar file

Tags: java, launch4j

I have created my project in U:/myproject where all the java stuff is installed in C: Drive. the jar file i created through netbeans is in u:/myproject/dist/myproject.jar. Could some one provided me the clean instructions of how to setup the launch4j and do i have to create a .exe file first?

or if i just sign the jar file, i will get this errror

```
output.exe is not a valid win32 application
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using Launch4J can be very simple. You only need your .JAR file to get your .EXE

I usually do the minimum step for my projects :

1) Build the program

2) Give the path to the .JAR file to Launch4j in the first page

3) Set an output for the .EXE file and the .XML results file in the first page

4) In the "JRE" page, set the min JRE version (eg : 1.1.0)

5) Execute !!!

And it should give a good .exe file.

Hope this helps !

Comment: Could you please explain, bit more about step 3, do I have create an .exe and .xml file first and where should i create?

Comment: Hum, normally Launch4J creates the .EXE file. You don't have to create it yourself. You only need to give the .JAR. to Launch4J and it will create the .EXE.

Comment: It was working now, but How can i link the lib folder, because the application is started, but its not connecting to the database, to pass/receive the data

Comment: Hum, can you explain a bit more how you are using your database ? Did you make a local test ? Is it online ?

Comment: small bug, it was fine now. Thank you.

Comment: A bit bad explanation. I had to execute my config file from prompt. Please, next time work harder on your reply, It didn't work to me as it didn't work for the people in the thread.