# Convert jar to exe

Tags: java, exe, launch4j

I try to convert a `jar` file to an `exe` file.

I followed the instructions provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15366461/instructions-to-setup-launch4j-for-jar-file) using `launch4j` .

I get only an `XML` file but no exe as expected.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should not, because that would kill the very purpose of Java

Comment: Java is born to be cross platform, exe is a Windows executable

Comment: So how should I deploy my application?

Comment: I don't see much benefit from trying to make an executable out of your jar file.  Whoever is going to run it still needs a JVM, they will still need to build an appropriate classpath, etc.  Just distribute the jar file(s).

Comment: The XML file is a results file.  Take a look at it and see if you can decern an error.  If not post the XML file to your question so we'd be better able to figure out the problem.

Comment: Ease of use for a Windows user should not be undervalued.

Answer (score 0):

> So how should I deploy my application?

Your user would have to have the JRE installed on their computer.  However, you could also distribute java.exe and rt.jar (the java run time jar) as well as any library jars you need for your application along with your program.  Since the java command has an optional classpath parameter you could write a batch file (something like runme.bat) which would look something like this:

java -cp rt.jar;myapplication.jar;otherjars.jar  MyMainClass

This is still Windows specific because the java.exe file would be a Windows specific file.  You could also add in logic to check for the environment variable JAVA_HOME and if that's set on the user's computer then the java program specific to their OS would be in JAVA_HOME/bin

Your real problem comes when you're not sure what operating system your user will be using AND you don't know if they have Java installed.  If you simply require that the user has the Java Runtime Environment installed then you're problem is solved for all users.

I hope that helps.
Greg